# C# 7.0 not supporting binary literal, although MSDN says it do supports

Tags: c#, mono, c#-7.0

I am using C# 7.0

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace myApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main () {
            int myValue = 0b0010_0110_0000_0011;
            Console.WriteLine(myValue);
        }
    }
}
```

On compiling it gives the error:

> error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `b0010_0110_0000_0011'

Why is this error coming? Because according to MSDN in C# 7.0 this is a valid syntax as it supports binary literals.

NOTE:

I am using mono beta version from repository http://www.mono-project.com/download/beta/ for Ubuntu Xenial

According to http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/ latest mono includes support for C# 7.0

Comment: Do other C#7 features work?

Comment: Till now I have not faced any trouble

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though... Have you got some modern C# 7 code running?

Comment: Please give me a code, I wil try and reply you the output

Comment: You have written both `main` and `writeLine` in camelCase when they should be in PascalCase, but that would give a different error. Are you using csc to compile (instead of msc)? Try if a local method works: `public static void Main() {
  Console.WriteLine(Add(2, 3));
  
  int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
 }`

Comment: @Dennis_E I am sorry I have corrected the code, still giving same error, I have saved the file as binary.cs, then used the commands mcs -out:binary.exe binary.cs, mono binary.exe

Comment: You need to compile with csc, not mcs. (The examples on the site are not updated for the new compiler)

Comment: @Dennis_E for your code getting the error error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `myApp.Program.Add(int, int)'

Comment: @Dennis_E Thanks using csc compiler the program is working perfectly with no more error